# How do we just recreate the database when I modify tables in sqldelight on Android

Tags: android, database-migration, sqldelight

I was just trying out [Sqldelight on Android](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/android_sqlite/) but can't seem to figure out an easy way to just drop and recreate the db on device when I've modified a table (or even added / deleted a new table).

The docs seems to indicate we need to create a <prev_version_number>.sqm file, which I did but just left it empty as I'd like to drop / recreate the tables in code using the `AndroidSqliteDriver.Callback` shown below (I just added a `println()` to see if it gets invoked for now), however this does not seem to be getting called when I modify the table (and/or add/delete a new table).

```
        return AndroidSqliteDriver(
        schema = MyDatabase.Schema,
        context = application,
        name = "myDb.db",
        callback = AndroidSqliteDriver.Callback(
            schema = MyDatabase.Schema,
            AfterVersionWithDriver(0) { println("DB Callback 0: AfterVersionWithDriver($it)") },
            AfterVersionWithDriver(1) { println("DB Callback 1: AfterVersionWithDriver($it)") },
        )
    )
```

Does anyone know how I could get this code inside the callback to execute on a migration or when it will be called by sqldelight?

Thanks.